# Global variable resetting

Tags: java, global-variables, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a list of arrays that i want to update, but it gives "index out of bounds" error. I can't seem to find the error. Need a pair of fresh eyes.

```
Global.variables.add(new String[]{(String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem(), jTextField2.getText(), jTextField3.getText(), (String) jComboBox2.getSelectedItem(), "Reservado"});

public void generateRandom() {
    for (int i = 0; i < Global.variables.size()-1; i++) {
        System.out.println("Searching "+Global.variables.get(i)[0]+" in temp "+i);
        for (int j = 0; j < temp.size()-1; j++) {
            System.out.println("Testing "+Global.variables.get(i)[0]+" with "+temp.get(j)+" "+j);
            if (Global.variables.get(i)[0].equals(temp.get(j))) {
                System.out.println("FOUND!");
                Global.variables.get(i)[4] = String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(Global.variables.get(i)[1]) + mt.nextGaussian() * Double.parseDouble(Global.variables.get(i)[2]));
                System.out.println(Global.variables.get(i)[0]+" = "+Global.variables.get(i)[4]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Global.variables contain (name, median, std, distribution, "reserved"); temp contains the name of some variables. So I try to run through the variables list see if they are in *temp* and update the "reserved" field...however: It gives me error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
```

Probably something easy but i can't seem to find what it is.

**Solved**: I was initializing Global.variables on another place, so some variables actually have the 5th element but others don't. Thanks :)

Comment: No [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (specifically the self-contained part) always makes it more difficult to help. Try `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Global.variables.get(i)));` just before the line throwing the exception. This may give some insight into the problem.

Comment: You need to debug it to see what index of List or array is out of bounds

Comment: You have 4 elements? And you are accessing the 4th element by putting 4?

Comment: @aksappy (name, median, std, distribution, "reserved") 5 elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are accessing `Global.variables.get(i)` in many places, which is returning an array, your are accessing it's element with out checking even if it exsist

```
Global.variables.get(i)[4]
Global.variables.get(i)[2]
```

you need to check the size and confirm if it is present, before trying to retrieve it.If the index is greater than or equal to the size() then you will get the exception